# How to apply a taxonomy condition using EntityFieldQuery?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

I have a content type where there is a tag field that is a taxonomy term.I would like to make a query to get all the nodes that contain the `$tag` variable inserted by the user. I know how to do it using `db_query` but if I use `EntityFieldQuery` seems that I cannot apply a join.

How can I do it? Do I have to use `db_query`?

Answer (score 1):

An `EntityFieldQuery` doesn't allow for `IS NOT NULL` or similar conditions, so there's no way to query for all nodes that contain a value for a particular field. You can only query nodes that have a *specific* value for a particular field.

They're also self-contained, so there's no way to add an extra join unless you implement `hook_query_alter()` and physically add the join once the query has been converted from an `EntityFieldQuery` to a standard `SelectQuery`. That, or sub-class `EntityFieldQuery` and add the new logic yourself.

That said you'll need to form the query yourself. If you're just querying for nodes though, I'd advise using the `taxonomy_index` table rather than the field tables, as that will produce cleaner queries and make life easier further down the line.